# Socle and minimal number of generators of an ideal in a regular local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, regular-rings, global-dimension

Let $(R, \mathfrak m, k)$ be a regular local ring of dimension $2$. Note that Hom$_R (k, M)$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space for any finitely generated $R$-module $M$ and Hom$_R (k, R/I) \cong (I:\mathfrak m)/I$ for any ideal $I$.

Then, is it true that  $1+ \dim_k$ Hom$_R(k, R/I)=\mu (I) $ ?

Note that $\mu (I)=\dim_k I/I\mathfrak m$.

Also, note that if $\mu(I)=n$, then $I$ has a minimal free resolution $0\to R^{n-1}\to R^n \to I\to 0$ . So in particular one also has a minimal free resolution $0\to R \to R^2 \to \mathfrak m \to 0$ .  I'm not sure whether these are helpful in the context or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. Starting with $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$, you get $\mathrm{Hom}(k,R/I)=\mathrm{Ext}^1(k,I)$, since $\mathrm{Ext}^1(k,R)=0$. From the exact sequence you have written, one has $0\to\mathrm{Ext}^1(k,I)\to\mathrm{Ext}^2(k,R^{n-1})\to\mathrm{Ext}^2(k,R^n)$. The last map is zero, since all are $k$-vector spaces and the minimality of the resolution says that all the entries in the map (thought of as a matrix over $R$, say) are in the maximal ideal. Now, $\mathrm{Ext}^2(k,R)=k$ and so you get $\dim_k\mathrm{Hom}(k,R/I)=\dim_k\mathrm{Ext}^1(k,I)=\dim_k\mathrm{Ext}^2(k,R^{n-1})=n-1$.

Comment: All the entries of the maps of the minimal free resolution are in the maximal ideal ...  from that why does it follow that the map Ext$^2(k, R^{n-1})\to $ Ext$^2(k, R^n)$ is zero ?

Comment: Both the modules are annihilated by the maximal ideal.

Comment: I see ... that makes sense ... so in saying this map is zero, we're not using regularity of $R$ anywhere right ? (apart from the fact that $I$ has a length $1$ resolution ...)